# Can `goto LABEL` cause a memory leak?

Tags: perl, memory, goto

Can using `goto` with labels cause memory leaks? All I found in the [documentation for `goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) that seems relevant is:

> The `goto LABEL` form finds the statement labeled with LABEL and resumes execution there.

Is it safe to use `goto LABEL`?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1159029 can help

Comment: In Perl, if you don't create any circular dependencies (ie. references to things that point back at themselves) that you manually purge, everything is cleaned up (automatic garbage collection) when the current scope exits. The final scope is the script file itself.

Comment: all that said, I'd recommend structuring code in a way that doesn't need `goto` (it's pretty easy). If in a loop, we have `next` and `last`.

Comment: @stevieb I'm not intending to use `goto` in my code, just wondering :) But what if we have a label and we `goto` it inside the same scope and in between we declare a variable? That's a bit unclear to me

Comment: capiche. Just putting it out there for others :) ++ on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1 minute of testing, the answer seems to be: <del>yes</del> **no** (see update below)

Watching `top` while this is running, `%MEM` continually increments

```
{
    THIS:
    my $x = 1;
    goto THIS;
}
```

This does not exhibit the same incrementing `%MEM` counter

```
while (1) {
    my $x = 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood the question. My take on the question was whether memory would be allocated for a lexical variable that already existed in that lexical scope with the use of a `goto`, and my test seems to say yes. Strictly speaking, this is not a memory leak. Should perl ever exit this lexical scope, the allocated space would be released.

Comment: not a leak, since perl doesn't lose track of the memory, and will free it all at scope exit.

Comment: just to make sure I got this, in your example, Perl will still track all the `my $x`s for each `goto` and in this case, will eventually fill all the available memory?

Comment: yonyon100: it seems so, yes. I only ran the first example for about 1 minute, and memory use continued to climb.